# This program is giving output "abc" for both p and c, but how?

Tags: c, pointers

When pc is assigning cdefg, why it is printing abc. when it goes to fun it is assigning pc= ""cdefg"

```
void fun(char *pc)
{
 pc = malloc(5);
 pc = "cdefg";
}

int main()
{
 char *p = "abc";
 char *c = p;
 fun(p);
 printf("%s %s\n",p,c);  
 }
```

Comment: You're assigning to pointer `pc` in `fun` and then leaving it dangling. (And you need strcpy, not assignment, and it needs to be length 6 to leave room for string terminator)

Comment: Also, you need a `n+1` size array for a string of size `n`.

Comment: C is pass by value, ever.

Comment: @errikos If OP was `strcpy()`ing the string, then yes. As it is, they allocate 5 bytes, then throw it's address away to be replaced by the address of the five+1 byte string (which is then thrown away when the function returns).

Comment: @TripeHound agreed, I was just pointing it out because the author seems to think that 5 characters are enough for a string of length 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. It actually updates the original pointer, rather than assigning to a copy which is then left dangling:

```
void fun(char **pc)
{
   *pc = malloc(6);
   strcpy(*pc, "cdefg");
}

int main()
{
   char *p = "abc";
   char *c = p;
   fun(&p);
   printf("%s %s\n",p,c);  
}
```

It also fixed 2 other problems. The buffer of size 5 isn't big enough for the string plus the string terminator character, and you also need to copy the string into the buffer - assignment won't work.

Answer (score 4):

The reason your program does what it does is that the assignment of `pc` in `fun` has nothing to do with assigning `p` in `main`. The pointer is passed by value; any changes made by `fun` get discarded.

If you would like to assign a new value inside a function, do one of three things:

- Pass a pointer to pointer, or
- Allocate a buffer in the caller, and pass it to the function, along with buffer's length, or
- Return the pointer from the function, and assign in the caller.

First approach:

```
void fun(char **ppc) {
    *ppc = "cdefg";
}
...
fun(&p); // in main
```

Second approach:

```
void fun(char *pc, size_t len) {
    if (len >= 6) {
        strcpy(pc, "cdefg");
    }
}
...
char p[20]; // in main
fun(p, 20);
```

Third approach:

```
char *fun() {
    return "sdefg";
}
...
char *p = fun(); // in main
```

Your program has other issues - for example, `malloc`-ed memory gets leaked by the assignment that follows.

Comment: You should add the buffer allocation and the call to the function in your second example because this version of `fun` is not compatible with the `main` function of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

When the function `fun` is called, the value of the pointer `p` is copied. Thus, only the local pointer `pc` in `fun` is changed. If you want to change the value of a pointer, you should take a double pointer as argument.

By the way, you do not have to call `malloc(3)` because the string `"cdefg"` is already present in memory (in rodata). The instruction `pc = "cdefg";` puts the address of `"cdefg"` into pc. You will loose the address of the memory allocated by `malloc(3)`, it's a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things at play here, passing by value and reassigning instead of copying.

If we start with the simple reassignment, take a closer look at these two lines:

```
pc = malloc(5);
pc = "cdefg";
```

The first lines assign to `pc`, making `pc` point to whatever memory `malloc` returned. The second line *reassigns* `pc` to point somewhere else. These two lines are basically the same as having an `int` variable `i` and doing

```
i = 1;
i = 2;
```

The first assignment you do is lost because the you immediately make another assignment. To make the memory returned by `malloc` contain the string `"cdefg"` there are two things you need to do: The first is that you need to allocate *six* characters, to fit the string terminator, and the second thing you need to do is to *copy* the string into the memory:

```
pc = malloc(strlen("cdefg") + 1);
strcpy(pc, "cdefg");
```

---

The second issue is more complex, and has to do with how arguments are passed in C. In C the arguments are passed *by values* which means they are copied and the function only have a local copy of the data in those arguments.

When you pass a pointer, like in your code, then the pointer is copied into the variable `pc`, and when the function returns the variable goes out of scope and all changes you made to the variable (like reassigning it to point somewhere else) are simply lost.

The solution is to pass arguments *by reference*. This is unfortunately not possible in C, but it can be *emulated* using pointers, or rather using pointers to variables. To pass a pointer to a variable that is a pointer, the type is a pointer to a pointer to some other type, so the function should take a pointer to a pointer to `char`:

```
void fun(char **ppc) { ... }
```

The variable `ppc` points to the variable `p` from the `main` function.

Now since `ppc` is pointing to a variable, you need to use the dereference operator to access the original variable:

```
*ppc = malloc(strlen("cdefg") + 1);
strcpy(*ppc, "cdefg");
```

To call the function you use the address-of operator `&` to create a pointer to the variable:

```
char *p = "abc";
...
fun(&p);
```

Comment: Preferable style is `malloc(5+1)` which is self-documenting code for "I have considered the null terminator".

Answer (score 0):

When you allocated the pointer again in caller function, the value of pointer variable changed. In order to take this new value to the calling function, you have to pass the address of the pointer. ie: pass the pointer by reference.

Answer (score -1):

Because 
  char *p - in main function
and 
  char *pc - in fun function
are different variables.